# DRBD8 and GFS on CentOS5

Tags: centos, drbd

I am trying to combine DRBD8 and GFS2 on CentOS5. Is there any possibility to do this without using a mulicast-cluster underneath? (CentOS seems to use AIS)

This is a two-node-cluster,  so a simple unicast setup should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is: Forget GFS in this case. Use OCFS2 instead.